# Selenium Java: Unable to Select Date from Date Picker

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I tried to select a date from custom date picker but it does not work.
[image]

[image]

The HTML is pasted as below along with the screenshot of how it looks.

HTML:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-datepicker-multi ui-datepicker-multi-3" style="position: absolute; top: 546px; left: 331px; z-index: 1; display: block; width: 51em;">
    <div class="ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-first">
        <div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-left"><a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" data-handler="prev" data-event="click" title="Prev"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span></a>
            <div class="ui-datepicker-title">
                <select class="ui-datepicker-month" data-handler="selectMonth" data-event="change">
                    <option value="0">Jan</option>
                    <option value="1" selected="selected">Feb</option>
                    <option value="2">Mar</option>
                    <option value="3">Apr</option>
                </select>&nbsp;<span class="ui-datepicker-year">2019</span></div>
        </div>
        <table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Sunday">Su</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Monday">Mo</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Tuesday">Tu</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Wednesday">We</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Thursday">Th</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Friday">Fr</span></th>
                    <th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Saturday">Sa</span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">1</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">2</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">3</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">4</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">5</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">6</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">7</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">9</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">10</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">11</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">12</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">13</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">14</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">15</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">16</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">17</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">18</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">19</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">20</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">21</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">23</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">24</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">25</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">26</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">27</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="1" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">28</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-middle">
        <div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
            <div class="ui-datepicker-title"><span class="ui-datepicker-month">March</span>&nbsp;<span class="ui-datepicker-year">2019</span></div>
        </div>
        <table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Sunday">Su</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Monday">Mo</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Tuesday">Tu</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Wednesday">We</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Thursday">Th</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Friday">Fr</span></th>
                    <th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Saturday">Sa</span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">1</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">2</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">3</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">4</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">5</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">6</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">7</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">9</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">10</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">11</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">12</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">13</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">14</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">15</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">16</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">17</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">18</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">19</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">20</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">21</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">23</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">24</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">25</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">26</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">27</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">28</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">29</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">30</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">31</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-last">
        <div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-right"><a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled" title="Next"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span></a>
            <div class="ui-datepicker-title"><span class="ui-datepicker-month">April</span>&nbsp;<span class="ui-datepicker-year">2019</span></div>
        </div>
        <table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Sunday">Su</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Monday">Mo</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Tuesday">Tu</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Wednesday">We</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Thursday">Th</span></th>
                    <th><span title="Friday">Fr</span></th>
                    <th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Saturday">Sa</span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="  ui-datepicker-current-day" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#">1</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">2</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">3</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">4</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">5</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">6</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">7</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">9</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">10</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">11</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">12</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">13</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">14</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">15</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">16</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">17</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">18</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">19</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">20</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">21</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">23</a></td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">24</a></td>
                    <td class="  ui-datepicker-today" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight" href="#">25</a></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">26</span></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">27</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">28</span></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">29</span></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">30</span></td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-datepicker-row-break"></div>
</div>
```

I had tried as

```
WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-state-default"));
List columns=(List) dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("ui-state-default"));
for (WebElement cell: columns){
      //Select 13th Date 
      if (cell.getText().equals("13")){
            cell.findElement(By.linkText("13")).click();
            break;
      }
}
```

and even tried to wait command so that the locator is found but no success.

> WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector

both didn't work as it failed to recognize the element can someone help me with this.
If possible can we even click the previous and next so that we can click some previous dates as well?

Comment: Post the HTML of the page instead of a screenshot of the code.

Comment: I have added the HTML as well @SAhmed .

Comment: There are more code for the datepicker. Please attach the full HTML of the datepicker with possibly one or two parent node

Comment: @SAhmed I have added some more in it.

Comment: This looks to me like you're using some javascript on top of the HTML you show - which might be why just looking at the HTML does not work here...

Comment: I tried to get the element by Using IDE but the browser crashes as soon as it is clicked.

Comment: What date are you trying to select and from which calendar? There are three calendars.

Comment: I couldn't select any of them apart from the first one which is by default. 
So any apart the first date would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did mistake using `By.tagName("ui-state-default")`, **ui-state-default** is a class not tag and your code below find nothing:

```
WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-state-default"));
List columns=(List) dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("ui-state-default"));
```

Code below return `a` with text **13** in the first month:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//a[.='13']")).click();
```

You can select last month if the date picker using `findElements`:

```
List<WebElement> dates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//a[.='13']"));
dates.get(2).click();
```

Also you can use `data-month` attribute:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//td[@data-month='3']/a[.='13']")).click();
```

Comment: for the second one,
it says to remove type arguments 
if that is done again a cast (List) driver needs to be done like List dates = (List) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//a[.='13']"));
which does not take .get(3)

Comment: `.get(3)` is wrong, last index is 2. You can get last using: `dates.get(dates.size()-1).click();`

Comment: The method get(String) in the type WebDriver is not applicable for the arguments (int)

 at newpackage1.flightdeckau.main(flightdeckau.java:91)

Comment: while running it through eclipse

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method get(String) in the type WebDriver is not applicable for the arguments (int)

 at newpackage1.flightdeckau.main(flightdeckau.java:91)

Comment: go to flightdeckau.java to the 91 row number, copy code and paste here

Comment: List dates = (List) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//a[.='13']"));
((WebDriver) dates).get(2).click();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192356/discussion-between-sers-and-user008).

Answer (score 1):

Using following xpath you can solve your problem easily without any hassle

```
//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//td[@data-month='2']//a[.='15']
```

Here i have select month **2** and date **15** to select the date. You can change data-month to select another.You can make it dynamic also.

I have tested this in chrome console and  my automation script it working fine for me

To verify paste following code in chrome console and hit inter>

```
$x("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//td[@data-month='2']//a[.='15']")
```

It will return the element of date 15 of second month.